# React Redux load data from firebase only once

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm making demo app. Data is stored in firebase. Now I'm loading data to my app just by axios get method. But from now I want add redux to my app. I saw some tutorials about connect firebase with redux, but my problem is that I want load data only once from firebase (on start app) and don't make any operation with firebase later. I mean after reload app I want to have this same initial state of application. Do you have any suggestion, I'm new with react and redux and don't have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Firebase documentation, specifically the section labeled [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once). From there comes this example:

> ```
> var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
> return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
>   var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
>   // ...
> });
> ```